# Java: Access method of another instance of same class

Tags: java

I'm new to this so sorry if i don't explain it great.

I have 2 class Interface and Depot.

I can call depot1.getName() and depot2.getName() in Instance class.
But I can't call them in Depot class as I am trying to check no instance of that class has the entered name:`(tempname.equals(depot1.getName()) || tempname.equals(depot2.getName()))`

Could it be because depot1 and depot2 haven't been created yet?

Here is getName

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

I think it may have to do with the fact that depot2 may not exist so i tried:

```
(depot2 != null && tempname.equals(depot2.getName()))
```

but that still gives more erors and won't let me compile

I am getting the following error "cannot find symbol - variable depot1"

Can I use isInstance? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: who says you can't call them in Depot class? as long as the instances are there, you can.

Comment: Some more code would help. As it is your question is hard to understand.

Comment: I am getting the error "cannot find symbol - variable depot1"

Comment: Have you got `Depot depot1 = new Depot() ` anywhere?

Comment: @Uskompuf that means you don't have an instance called depot1.

Comment: Show us the full code where you do `(tempname.equals(depot1.getName())`, I assume you don't have such a variable

Comment: Unless OP provides the relevant code, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: how can i check if that instance exists and if it does if its name is equal then i tried (depot2 != null && tempname.equals(depot2.getName()))

Comment: As others already said: post the code/class where you define `depot1` and `depot2` as well as the class and method where you call `tempname.equals(depot1.getName())` etc. The error you get states that the compiler doesn't know `depot1`, i.e. that variable either doesn't exist or isn't visible at the location where you want to access it - we're trying to help here but without seeing more relevant code all we can do is point you to any of the numerous tutorials or reiterate their contents (and why should we do that if we can simply point you somewhere else?).

Comment: @Thomas the instance doesn't exist i need to check if it does first

Comment: Read those comments carefully: we're talking about the _variables_ aka _references_ and not about the instances. If you want to check whether an instance exists then you need a variable and check whether it references the correct instance. It's like if you want to check whether someone is at home: without the address you can't do that. So you need that variable/reference/address first.

Comment: Nearly half an hour and still no compilable example code.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your code don't have instance of `depot1` create a instance using `new` like following snippet: This is not exact answer but it will help you.

```
package com.test;
class Depot
{
   private String name;

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName( String name )
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

}

public class Test
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Depot depot1 = new Depot();
      depot1.setName( "depot1" );

      Depot depot2 = new Depot();
      depot2.setName( "depot2" );

      // Rest of code
      //(tempname.equals(depot1.getName()) || tempname.equals(depot2.getName()))
   }
}
```

Comment: problem is i don't want to create the depot how can i check if depot2 exists then if so does its name match?

Comment: how you are getting `depot2` ? So we can check if `depot2` is exists or not.

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean i create depot1 in instance then it runs depot1 setName where it checks if it collides with any other depot names but i can't as im asking it to check an instance which might not exist